# angular 2:how create object, translating the angular to angular2

Tags: function, object, angular, authentication

I studying angular 2 and I m having a problem.

I don't know how create object in my login function (Angular1)

```
    public logIn() {
        let phone = this.user.number.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        let email = 'u' + phone + '@lunch24.com';
        this.af.auth.login({email: email, password: this.user.password})
            .then((state) => {
                console.log(state)
                var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('v1/users');
                this.af.database.object(usersRef.child(state.uid))
                    .subscribe((snapshot) => {
                        console.log(snapshot)
                        var user = snapshot;
                        if (user.roles.driver != true) {
                            if (user.roles.admin) {
                                var admin = 1;
                            } else {
                                var admin = 0;
                            }
                            if (user.roles.operator) {
                                var operator = 1;
                            } else {
                                var operator = 0;
                            }
                            if (user.roles.individual_customer) {
                                var individual_customer = 1;
                            } else {
                                var individual_customer = 0;
                            }
```

Comment: var myobj = {};

Comment: @ Lajos Arpad so in constructor add
        this.user = {};
an in dunction somthing like this
this.user.admin = user.roles.admin;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.user = {
                            admin: snapshot.roles.admin,
                            operator: snapshot.roles.operator
```